# quisiera separar con metodo split y mapear un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, map, split

hola quisiera una ayuda de como puedo separar un array con split que tiene un objeto que tiene sus propiedades que tiene un name , curso1 , curso2 y curso3 que esta vacio. los cursos que tienen texto y que estan en su contenido con signo + separarlos en un array con la propiedad split, y luego encapsular en un array de objeto llamado cursos y finalmente mostrarlo como objeto el array original.

por fabor ayudenme les boya agradecer.

aqui estube haciendo el codigo pero no me funciona

```js
var alumno: [
          {
          'name' : 'ivan hambi apaza',
          'curso1' : 'HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16',
          'curso2' : 'HISTORIA+3+17',
          'curso3' : '',
          }
],
       

alumnoN(){
var newArr = [...this.alumno]
              newArr.map(el => {
              return el.curso1 = el.curso1.split('+')
              })
              newArr.map(el => {
              return el.curso2 = el.curso2.split('+')
              })
              newArr.map(el => {
              return el.curso3 = el.curso3.split('+')
              })
              
    return newArr
}

  
console.log(alumnoN())
```

quisiera como resultado un objeto como esta:

```
alumno:{
      'name':'ivan hambi apaza',
      'cursos':[
               ['HISTORIA DE LA DANZA',2,16],
               ['HISTORIA',3,17],
              ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás ejecutando [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) sin asignarlo a otra variable y por eso es que no ves resultados.

Aparte, no es necesario ejecutarlo varias veces, basta con una, donde definas el objeto a retornar y vayas agregando los cursos, si es que existen y no tienen valor ["Falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

```js
var alumno = [
    {
        "name": "ivan hambi apaza",
        "curso1": "HISTORIA DE LA DANZA+2+16",
        "curso2" : "HISTORIA+3+17",
        "curso3" : ""
    }
];
       

function alumnoN() {
    // Devolver sin asignar a otra variable, no es necesario
    return alumno.map(el => {
        // Crear el objeto a devolver con datos básicos
        var ret = {
            "nombre": el.name,
            "cursos": []
        };
        // Agregar solo si existe y no tiene un valor "falsy"
        if(el.curso1) ret.cursos.push(el.curso1.split('+'));
        if(el.curso2) ret.cursos.push(el.curso2.split('+'));
        if(el.curso3) ret.cursos.push(el.curso3.split('+'));
        // Devolver el objeto
        return ret;
    });
}
console.log(alumnoN());
```

Comment: exelente amigo te doy tu like. una ultima quisiera quitar el formato array del primer nivel 
  {
    "nombre": "ivan hambi apaza",
    "cursos": [
      [
        "HISTORIA DE LA DANZA",
        "2",
        "16"
      ],
      [
        "HISTORIA",
        "3",
        "17"
      ]
    ]
  }

Comment: `return ret[0];`